# How do I use the Temperature Performance Monitor in C#.NET?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to create an application using speech for the blind and visually impaired that tells you the system uptime, how much RAM you have available, current CPU load, and other stuff like that, and I ran into an issue; I cannot get the Temperature Performance Counter to work properly

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;
using System.Speech.Synthesis;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        private static SpeechSynthesizer synth = new SpeechSynthesizer();
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<string> cpuMaxedOutMessage = new List<string>();
            cpuMaxedOutMessage.Add("WARNING: Reduce the load on your CPU!");
            cpuMaxedOutMessage.Add("Don't push your CPU so hard! Your CPU usage is at 100%");
            cpuMaxedOutMessage.Add("CPU OVERLOAD!");
            cpuMaxedOutMessage.Add("Congratulations. You have officially maxed your CPU.");
            cpuMaxedOutMessage.Add("WARNING: Reduce the load on your CPU!");

            Random rand = new Random();

            synth.Speak("Welcome to System Resource Monitor: Vocal Edition Version 1.0");

            PerformanceCounter perfCpuCount = new PerformanceCounter("Processor Information","% Processor Time","_Total");
            perfCpuCount.NextValue();
            PerformanceCounter perfMemCount = new PerformanceCounter("Memory", "Available Mbytes");
            perfMemCount.NextValue();
            PerformanceCounter perfUptimeCount = new PerformanceCounter("System", "System Up Time");
            perfUptimeCount.NextValue();
            PerformanceCounter perfTempZone = new PerformanceCounter("Thermal Zone Information", "Temperature", "\_TZ.TZ00");
            perfTempZone.NextValue();

            TimeSpan uptimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(perfUptimeCount.NextValue());
            string systemUptimeMessage = String.Format("The current system up time is {0} days {1} hours {2} minutes {3} seconds", (int)uptimeSpan.TotalDays, (int)uptimeSpan.Hours, (int)uptimeSpan.Minutes, (int)uptimeSpan.Seconds);

            JoshSpeak(systemUptimeMessage, VoiceGender.Male, 2);

            int speechSpeed = 1;

            while (true)
            {
                int currentCpuPercentage = (int)perfCpuCount.NextValue();
                int currentAvailableMemory = (int)perfMemCount.NextValue();
                int currentTemp = (int)perfTempZone.NextValue();


                Console.WriteLine("CPU load: {0}%", currentCpuPercentage);
                Console.WriteLine("Available Memory: {0}MB", currentAvailableMemory);
                Console.WriteLine("Your Current Temperature is: {0} degrees", currentTemp);

                    if (currentCpuPercentage == 100)
                    {
                        if(speechSpeed < 5)
                        {
                            speechSpeed++;
                        }
                        string cpuLoadVocalMessage = cpuMaxedOutMessage[rand.Next(4)];
                        JoshSpeak(cpuLoadVocalMessage,VoiceGender.Male, speechSpeed++);
                    }
                    else
                    {

                        string cpuLoadVocalMessage = String.Format("The current CPU load is {0} percent", currentCpuPercentage);
                        JoshSpeak(cpuLoadVocalMessage, VoiceGender.Male, 2);
                    }

                    string memAvailableVocalMessage = String.Format("You currently have {0} megabytes of memory available", currentAvailableMemory);
                    JoshSpeak(memAvailableVocalMessage, VoiceGender.Male, 2);

                string tempVocalMessage = String.Format("You computer's current temperature is {0} degrees", currentTemp);
                JoshSpeak(tempVocalMessage, VoiceGender.Male, 2); 

                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
        }
        public static void JoshSpeak(string message, VoiceGender voiceGender)
        {
            synth.SelectVoiceByHints(voiceGender);
            synth.Speak(message);
        }
        public static void JoshSpeak(string message, VoiceGender voiceGender, int rate)
        {
            synth.Rate = rate;
            JoshSpeak(message, voiceGender);
        }
    }
}
```

The error output is as follows:

> Code: CS1009
>   Description: Unrecognized escape sequence
>   Line 35

Comment: That's a compile-time error, right?  What is the line of code at line 35?

Comment: maybe change the name of this question to something like "What causes this Unrecognized escape sequence" ?

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
PerformanceCounter perfTempZone = new PerformanceCounter("Thermal Zone Information", "Temperature", "\_TZ.TZ00");
```

with
`@"\_TZ.TZ00"` instead of `"\_TZ.TZ00"`

The compiler interprets the backslash as starting an escape sequence. You can tell it to take the input literally with `@` in front of the string.

Comment: Didn't work. Still the same error message.